# Replace part of a string in python for a bs4 script?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a BS4 script that scrapes for links. It returns something that looks like this: "/watch/f568a5e2sdfd783"

I put that into Excel to mass convert it to look like: https://website.com/f568a5e2sdfd783.jpg"

How do I modify the code below to skip the manual Excel step and just replace "/watch/" with "https://website.com/" and add the `".jpg"` at the end before it prints the link?

Code:

```
    page = requests.get(URL)
    time.sleep(1)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    for links in soup.find('div',id='view').find_all('a'):
        print(links['href'])
except:
    continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work for your case:

```
website = "https://website.com/"

for links in soup.find('div',id='view').find_all('a'):
    parts = links['href'].split("/")
    new_link = parts[1].replace(parts[1], website) + '/'.join(parts[2:]) + ".jpg"
    print(new_link)
```